# bootstrap creative template errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a WordPress site using the bootstap creative theme. I have been muddling on and doing ok but I have now hit a wall.

I have uncaught errors showing in google chrome which I need help to fix:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery.easing.min.js:44

Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at creative.min.js:6

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery.easing.min.js:44
```

Source files are public so what you require should be [here](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-creative).

I have not played around with any of these files but please let me know if you require my files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery.

**The not so clean solution**

First install [Insert Headers and Footers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/)

Then go Settings > Insert Headers and Footers.

Finally copy/past this code in "Scripts in header"

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js></script>
```

**The best solution**

Simply add this code to the header of your theme's html code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js></script>
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you so much for saving me hours of time in the name of pride.